# Recursive Collatz With Various Display Modes

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following information for an assignment:

```
## CollatzRecursion


###
# define your RECURSIVE version of Collatz below this comment so that it runs
# correctly when called from below.
#
# REQUIREMENTS:
#  a) The correct sequence must be printed, all the values on one line.
#  b) Your Collatz function must use recursion.
#  c) Aside from two arguments accepting a positive integer value and the letter
#     F, B, or P; your Collatz function MAY NOT use any other internal or external variables.
#  d) Your Collatz function may accept only the two arguments described in (c).
#  e) If the second argument is 'F', the sequence should b printed in its
#     naturally generated order.
#     If the second argument is 'B', the sequence should be printed in reverse.
#     If the second argument is 'P', then a palindrome of the sequence values should 
#     be printed (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome).  In this case
#     it doesn't matter if your function prints the first value as 1 or the
#     value provided by the user.
###

###
# Do NOT alter Python code below this line
###
m = input( "Enter a positive integer value: " )
displaymode = ''  # initialize to anything not F, B, P
while displaymode not in ['F', 'B', 'P'] :
displaymode = raw_input( "Choose a display mode:  F=forward, B=backward, P=palindrome: " )

Collatz( m, displaymode )
print
```

I am unsure of how I could start this problem, but I am thinking this will involve adding the values in the sequence to an array so that they can be printed backwards and as a palindrome. I would just like some pointers/advice that will get me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a list (or any other type of array) because the instructions tell you that "your Collatz function MAY NOT use any other internal or external variables". That restriction is also a hint: you need to print the Collatz sequence values at the appropriate time during the recursion.

It's hard to give further hints without writing the code for you, and I know you don't want that. But here's a version that prints the sequence in its naturally generated order, and with a bit of thought about how the recursion works you should be able to figure out how to modify it so that the sequence is printed in reverse order. And once you've done that it's easy to get it to do it palindromically.

```
def collatz(m):
    print m,
    if m > 1:
        collatz(3 * m + 1 if m % 2 else m // 2)

# test

collatz(7)
print
```

**output**

```
7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

---

P.S. Your teacher *should* be teaching you Python 3 as Python 2 will no longer be supported after 2020.